# How to get selected option of the attribute for the product?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, option, labels

Struggling to get value of the selected option for product.

Example:Product require assembly so created attribute `dropdown`
Below few methods I've tried

```
echo $data = $_product->getAssembly();
echo $label = $_product->getAttributeText('Assembly');

$_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('assembly');
$attribute_label = $_attribute->getStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName());

echo 'Label: '.$attribute_label;//empty
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','assembly');

$attributeModel->getData('label');
echo 'Model: '.$attributeModel;// empty
$atributeCode = 'assembly';

$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$atributeCode);
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

`var_dump` is displaying only an array of all options.

**How can I get  it ?**

Comment: SO this was right: echo $data = $_product->getAssembly();
echo $label = $_product->getAttributeText('Assembly'); the only problem was capital "A" :) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_product->getAssembly()` should return you the id of the option selected for the current product.

`$_product->getAttributeText('assembly')` (notice the lowercase attribute name) should return you the label of the selected assembly option for the current product.

But there is a catch.
If you are trying these in the product list page or somewhere where the `$_product` is one iteration from a product collection you have to mark the `assembly` attribute as "Used in product listing" and rebuild your product flat indexes in order to work.